# function is not being called in Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, visual-studio-code

new to Javascript and it's quirks. Can somebody explain this to me? it works fine in CodeSandbox, but in VSCode and Chrome I'm hitting this problem:

setup() function not called in this code:

```
function init(){
  ...
}

function setup(){
  ...
}

init();
setup();
```

setup() function being called in this code:

```
function init(){
  ...
  setup();
}

function setup(){
  ...
}

init();
```

Why does it execute in the last example, but not in the first?

Comment: That *should* work either way as far as I can tell. Is this exactly how the code is structured in your actual project?

Comment: Could you show the entire code of init() ? Maybe you have some infinit loop in it and it never calls the next function...

Comment: whats iniside the init of the first example?

Comment: function init () {

  window.ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
  window.ctx.fillRect(0,0,800,400);
  
}

Comment: @llamaCaraDara edit your question rather than add code in the comments. How do you know that setup() is never called? Show this code as well.

Comment: @llamaCaraDara, it would be more clear if you can share your working sandbox...

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-moore-bnxpq?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 1):

Just remove this line `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init)` and you're good to go.

`DOMContentLoaded` event is fired when your page is fully loaded and parsed. So, the following scenario was happening:

```
init();
setup();
init(); <--- due to DOMContentLoaded event
```

Comment: Yup! that's what was happening. Thank you!